# Issue trying to remove entries on one page not displaying on another

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I'm very new to EE so forgive my lack of actual knowledge of the correct terms for channels/entries etc.

We have page entries (the coloured blocks of text)on our charity website which allows you to make a donation to a specific fund - https://www.royalfreecharity.org/give/funds

I want to be able to remove the individual items from this page but when we do it removes the entry from the drop down list on our general funds donation page - https://www.royalfreecharity.org/donate/fund.

is there a way of changing the coding so that if we turn off the entry in one list it will still appear on the drop down donation page.

Here is the current template code

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="donate_funds" 
    disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
} 
<div class="grid6 [...]"> 
    <div class="grid-donate" style="[...]"> 
        <a href="{url_title_path='donate/fund'}" class="grid-link">
           <h2 class="grid-heading">{title}</h2> 
           <p class="grid-summary">{donate_summary}</p> 
                [...]
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your relevant template code in your question? You will get better answers if you do. That said, I'd look at using categories or statuses to allow you to get certain subsets of Channel entries in different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the code below if from our template manager for our give funds

Comment: {exp:channel:entries channel="donate_funds" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
<div class="grid6 {switch='grid6-1|grid6-2|grid6-3|grid6-4|grid6-5|grid6-6'}">
<div class="grid-donate" style="padding:1em;background:{switch='#D40092|#FE0000|#F95900|#19A8E1|#009F8D|#8CAA32'}">
<a href="{url_title_path='donate/fund'}" class="grid-link">
 <h2 class="grid-heading">{title}</h2>
 <p class="grid-summary">{donate_summary}</p>

Comment: I've tried to look at the status and sticky code additions in the {exp.channel section and have  managed to get the boxes to disappear from the page and they're still in the donate drop down but I cannot add them individually back onto the first page.

Comment: Based on what I see of your template code (I added it to your question), I'd recommend using categories for this Channel -- perhaps a "visibility" category group, with a category for each location you want it to show up. That way for any given entry you can apply one or more categories to an entry and it will show up in the places you want it to on the front end. The `channel:entries` tag accepts a `category` parameter.  https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#category

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is through the use of categories. You can set up a new category group (eg Menu and Listing Visibility), assign it to this Channel, then create categories that control where you want an entry to appear.

- show on main listing
- show in menu
- etc

Just assign categories as appropriate for the entry. Then in your templates you can use the [`category` parameter](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#category) on your various `channel:entries` tags to out[ut the desired entries.

There are other ways of doing this, for sure, but based on what I know about your setup I think this would be a good route. And the Edit entries page in EE has good category filtering, as well as the ability to apply/remove categories en-masse.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a [toggle field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/toggle.html) to your channel called "visible", and then add a [search parameter](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) to the channel: entries tag to limit the results to only those entries that have the "visible" field set.  So your tag in you code example changes to become:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="donate_funds" 
    disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
    search:visible="1"
}
```

If you then use the same channel entries call elsewhere (e.g. when generating your menu) and leave out the search parameter you will get all the entries listed there.

This is similar to the approach suggested by Alex, but perhaps simpler if all you are wanting to do is not show the entries in some places.

HTH